# Ember.js - HOWTO load a subclass data model into a superclass's route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to load a subclass data model into a superclass's route?

As an example, I have a superclass named `Vehicle` and a subclass named `Car`.

I have route like this:

```
/vehicle/21/edit
```

And in this instance, `Vehicle #21` is a `Car`. Accrodingly, my API returns the following payload data:

```
{"car": {/* lots of data */}}
```

When the route `vehicle.edit` tries to load this data, I get the following error:

```
Error while processing route: vehicle.edit payload.data is null
```

I can work around this by changing my API so that it uses `vehicle` as the root node in the JSON response, but I was wondering if Ember has a way to automatically cast a subclass into a superclass (e.g., load the `car` JSON response into a `Vehicle` instance).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the point of having subclasses then?

Comment: @ChristopherMilne Precisely the reason why I'm asking as the workaround defeats the purpose of subclasses. Thanks for your commentary.

Answer (score 1):

Today emberjs/data only supports [polymorphism](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/models/relationships/#toc_polymorphism) for relationships.

I.e. you can define following model:

```
//models/blog-post.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  post: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { polymorphic: true }) //i.e. pic-comment, text-comment
});
```

What you want is to call polymorphic data from store:

```
this.get('store').findRecord('vehicle', 21);
```

But this is not possible at the moment. There's an [open RFC out there](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/polymorphism/text/0000-find-polymorphism.md). So maybe this is possible in future.

Comment: Thanks, wuarmin. Not what I was expecting as there is no relationship for which these vehicles and cars are being loaded into. It's a direct call to the `/vehicle/:id/edit` route which pulls directly from the vehicle/car store, not an associated route (i.e.,  `/car-driver`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your payload looks like, you can approach this in a couple of different ways.
If you have access to how the payload is being sent, the most elegant way to deal with it would be to use hasMany relationship.
Else, in the route, you can make the call in your model hook and return that data to be used by vehicle.edit route.

Comment: Thanks, Chhirag. Are you able to elaborate your answer?

Comment: I will need more info, do you want to put it in a twiddle?